# Point a local domain to localhost:3000

Tags: apache2, virtual-hosts

Hey, I would love to point a local domain to localhost:3000 or other ports on which I am running my Wubrick instances (for Rails)

**I can not find an apache2 config to point a local domain to these wubrick instances (or simply localhost:3000). Can some one please help me with that?**

Regards,
Nikhil Gupta

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK. Found the solution, as below:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerName rails.new
    ServerAlias www.rails.new rails
    PassengerEnabled Off
    ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:3000/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:3000/
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: How does this work, doesn't *:80 mean look for port 80?

Comment: @Justin, ProxyPass makes the job. You create a kind of gateway to your app running on a different IP/port.

Comment: @Stoic, I'll mention that one might have to enable mod_proxy before. `sudo a2enmod mod_proxy`